# Siebel Input / output parsing

Tags: xml-parsing, workflow, siebel

Could someone please explain me how to convert the below siebel workflow step input format into readable one? Is there any tool for converting the input and output to XML format?

'''@0*0*0*1*0*0*3*1*13*siebel message3*0*7*Message.... '''